# How did it come to be that EF is trying to save thousands of entities simultaneously?

Tags: entity-framework-core

#### TLDR

If I were to call EF like this:

```
dbcontext.Update(newEntityA);
dbContext.Save();
dbcontext.Update(newEntityB);
dbContext.Save();
```

and it all completed successfully in < 1 millisecond, how many INSERT statements would it execute? Two inserts with X parameters each or one insert with 2X parameters and a VALUES line that was a `( (...), (...) )` ?

If the first insert failed because of eg PK violation, does it change the answer?

#### Long version

I've a very simple app that moves data from a RabbitMQ to an Azure SQL database. The app looks something like this (I've stripped out most of the setup/logging calls):

```
class Program
{

    private static IConfigurationRoot _configuration;
    private static IConsumer _consumer;
    private static ConsumerDbContext _dbContext;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        _configuration = builder.Build();

        _dbContext = new ConsumerDbContext(...configblah...);
        _consumer = new RabbitMqConsumer(...configblah...);
        _consumer.Connect();
        _consumer.ReceivedMessage += ConsumerOnReceivedMessage;

    }


    private static void ConsumerOnReceivedMessage(object sender, MessageArgs messageArgs)
    {
        try{

            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DrawingModel>(messageArgs.Message.ToString());

            if (model != null)
            {
                var drawing = _dbContext.Drawings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.DrawingId);
                if (drawing != null)
                {
                    if (drawing.DrawingCommandModel != null)
                    {
                        var command = new DrawingCommandEntity(model.DrawingCommandModel);
                        command.Id = model.DrawingCommandId;
                        _dbContext.Add(command);
                    }
                    drawing.LastExecutedCommandId = model.DrawingCommandId;
                    drawing.CurrentState = model.DrawingState;
                    _dbContext.Update(drawing);
                    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
                _logger.LogInformation("success ...");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("fail .....");
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially the RMQ contains JSON that describes the current state of a vector drawing and the the command that led to the current state. Drawing has many DrawingCommand, and the Drawing.CurrentState is a concatenation/convergence of multiple DrawingCommand. A DrawingCommand is of the ilk *"draw a green line width 5px from 0,0 to 10,10"* and the commands themselves may have a history of changes - if the user changes the green to blue, then the change is processed as two drawing commands - firstly that the command was created as green and then later that it was changed to blue so a new drawing command like *"draw a blue line width 5px from 0,0 to 10,10"* is written.

This allows undo/redo, so the CurrentState of a Drawing can be conceived as the latest set of unique DrawingCommands. Every change that is ever performed on a Drawing's DrawingCommand list is stored, whether it's addition, removal or changing of the DrawingCommand entities

The JSON is entirely calculated elsewhere; multiple systems submit DrawingCommand JSON to a central aggregator, the aggregator maintains the current state of a Drawing and all the DrawingCommand that compose it, and emits the results into an RMQ. The RMQ is used to coalesce the work so that a single app (this app) can connect to Azure and load the data into the DB. This means the RMQ already contains all the primary key guids for a drawing and the drawing entities, and literally the only thing this app does is deser the JSON to a DB entity and insert it.

It does it this way because there is a limit to the number of connections we can make to the azure DB and coalescing things via a queue is the best way to reduce load and work within the connections limit on Azure

**So, to the problem:**

Recently, we ended up with a situation where messages were piling into the RMQ and the consumer wouldn't process them. After altering the logging level to minimum of Info (granted, logging an exception with info level isn't great) rather than Error I hit the button in Azure management portal to restart the service.

Looking at the log (logging to azure blob storage, a new file created on that day) it became apparent that a duplicate GUID PK had entered the queue and was breaking the INSERT query formed by EF. To my surprise though when pulling the logs, the queries EF was forming were enormous:

```
date,level,message
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      Failed executing DbCommand (2,689ms) [Parameters=  .... 1.4 megabytes of data snipped ... ]
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,      SET NOCOUNT ON;,
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      INSERT INTO [DrawingCommands] ([Id], [CommandType], [CreatedDate], [CurrentState], [CustomerId], [ObjectsIds], [PreviousState], [ToolType], [DrawingId])"
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8),",
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      (@p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17),",
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      (@p18, @p19, @p20, @p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, @p25, @p26),",
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      (@p27, @p28, @p29, @p30, @p31, @p32, @p33, @p34, @p35),",
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      (@p36, @p37, @p38, @p39, @p40, @p41, @p42, @p43, @p44),",
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      (@p45, @p46, @p47, @p48, @p49, @p50, @p51, @p52, @p53),",
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      (@p54, @p55, @p56, @p57, @p58, @p59, @p60, @p61, @p62),",
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      (@p63, @p64, @p65, @p66, @p67, @p68, @p69, @p70, @p71),",
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      (@p72, @p73, @p74, @p75, @p76, @p77, @p78, @p79, @p80),",
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      (@p81, @p82, @p83, @p84, @p85, @p86, @p87, @p88, @p89),",
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      (@p90, @p91, @p92, @p93, @p94, @p95, @p96, @p97, @p98),",
2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      (@p99, @p100, @p101, @p102, @p103, @p104, @p105, @p106, @p107),",

...

2019-09-20T11:52:02,Inf,"      (@p2088, @p2089, @p2090, @p2091, @p2092, @p2093, @p2094, @p2095, @p2096);",
```

1.4 megabytes worth of data makes up the parameters line, over 2096 parameters

I'm curious to know how it came to be that EF was trying to save approx 232 drawing commands in one go. I'm also curious how it comes to be that this is the very first thing in the log.

I suspect that the tracked entities are added to with the `Update()` call and saved in the `Save()` call. If `Save()` fails then the entity remains unsaved in the tracked entity list and when another queue message is processed and added with `Update()`, then the `Save()` will be attempted again - this time there are two entities in the list, so 9 parameters will become 18.. And so on, until the graph of entities to be saved is huge..

Is this the case?

Any thoughts on why I didn't see a succession of error messages where the number of parameters repeatedly increased all the way up to 2096? Literally the first entry in the log after reconfiguring the min logging level to information had 2096 parameters.

Is there a possibility that the log level change was picked up immediately but the request from the azure management panel to restart the service was processed later? Immediately after the final massive query in the logs I see "thread was being aborted", then the service goes back to normal, inserting one entity at a time. I'm thinking that either EF coalesces db writes, so it doesn't do the `Save()` immediately if another `Save()` follows within a very short timescale.. or it's that the log level change reflected immediately, so the first log entries were jsut of those final seconds where the app was still running through its old object list. Restarting the app deleted the entire set of unsaved entities which allowed things to proceed normally

Comment: Thats alot of context. What happens if you wrap the code in a transaction? The behavior you describe around SaveChanges seem [pretty spot on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#default-transaction-behavior).

Comment: I suspect nothing would change, actually. It's sort of "implied transactional" because it's just a single update statement with 2096 parameters, rather than "explicit transactional" - 232 insert statements with 9 parameters each, in a transaction. Indeed, later in the log there were more insert statements per execution - two tables and an insert statement like `INSERT A VALUES  (@p0, @p1), (@p2, @p3); INSERT B VALUES (@p4), (@p5);` - except there were thousands of parameters there too. Curious if this is how EF achieves all-or-nothing in the absence of explicit transaction calls

Comment: If EF cannot save the entity, thats your issue (not thousands of parameters). I really got nothing, I'm just assuming you're missing some output somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

EF couldn't save the entity, due to a PK violation. Because the db context was a singleton, the list of tracked entities was just growing and growing every time it tried; more entities would be added and still the first would fail to save.

I changed the scope of the DB context so it was created anew on every cycle of processing a message from the queue. In this way entities that didn't save correctly would be forgotten when the dbcontext was renewed (and we don't care about them being lost since they are corrupt anyway) which stopped it from getting stuck on one failed entity with a massive backlog